# Basic CKEditor setup with JQuery and a custom config file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

This is my first time using CKeditor and I am trying to get some of the basics working.  I have a test page, (not PHP, just basic HTML) with JQuery and Bootstrap loaded and working OK.  I have two  fields. I have linked to the CKEditor CDN and loaded adapt_jquery.js in the `<head>`

Relevant HTML

If I place this script at the bottom of the page, I get an instance of CKEditor on each `<textarea>` with the specified ui color and size.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('textarea').ckeditor(
   {
    uiColor : '#03BC5D',
    language : 'en',
    height : 100,
    width : 600 ,  
   }
);
</script>
```

If I use the script below on the page, an editor is rendered for each `<textarea>`, and The Firefox web developer plug in shows that custom_config.js is in the list of Javascript files.  However the editor instance that loads for each `<textarea>` had not been affected by my custom config file. I expect that I am missing something simple, but can't figure out what.

```
 <script>
  $('textarea').ckeditor(
   {
      customConfig : '/JQTesting/ck_custom/custom_config.js'       
    }
  );
 </script>
```

Custom Config File:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    uiColor : '#03BC5D';
    language : 'en';
    height : 100;
    width : 600;
};
```

Comment: Is there any console error or warning saying it can't find the file perhaps?

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I was getting a JS error: missing semi-colons after each declaration in the custom_config.js file. Corrected it, no longer getting errors, but the editor is still not affected by the custom config file. I  edited my original post to reflect the changes.

Comment: Cool. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: I am no longer getting errors, but it still does not work.  The editor instances are still not being affected by the custom config file.  It its just that I am no longer getting JS errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the properties of the `config` parameter, so you code has to look like this

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.uiColor = '#03BC5D';
    config.language = 'en';
    config.height = 100;
    config.width = 600;
};
```

You created different labels ([MDN: label](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)) in your function by using the `:` outside of an *object literal*. As of that you didn't change `config` and your `editorConfig` function didn't do anything.

Comment: Thank you. That was simple.  I was following the pattern of a config.js  file that I found.   Should have looked at more.